# following url: curl couldn't resolve host 'GET'

Tags: php, mysql, bash, curl

I have a page (realized with a php framework) that add records in a MySQL db in this way:
www.mysite.ext/controller/addRecord.php?id=number
that add a row in a table with the number id passed via post and other informations such as timestamp, etc.
So, I movedo my eintire web applicazione to another domain and all HTTP requests works fine from old to new domain.
Only remaining issue is the curl: I wrote a bash script (under linux) that run curl of this link. Now, obviously it does not works because curl returns an alert message in which I read the page was moved.
Ok, I edited the curl sintax in this way

```
#! /bin/sh
link="www.myoldsite.ext/controlloer/addRecord.php?id=number"
curl --request -L GET $link
```

I add **-L** to follow url in new location but curl returns the error I wrote in this topic title.
It would be easier if I could directly modify the link adding the new domain but I do not have physical access to all devices.

Comment: "curl couldn't resolve host 'GET'" says it all. -L doesn't expect GET as parameter.  so curl attempts to fetch the URL GET, or read from host with name GET. it doens't resolve, and you ought to add that hostname to your hosts file, with the ip address it should have, if your intention is really to contact host GET. If you intend ito force a GET rather than PUT request for exchanging data, look at option -G instead

Comment: `GET` should be the default anyway, no reason to set it.

Comment: is there a way to solve this issue without having physical access to all devices in which I must to apply this "patch"?
  I think it has no sense to edit curl since I have not access to this machines.
  Can I do that from web?

Comment: No, you cannot. The arguments you are passing to `curl` are invalid. This has nothing to do with your web server, so nothing you do to your web server could possibly change it.

Answer (score 4):

[`GET` is the default request](http://httpkit.com/resources/HTTP-from-the-Command-Line/) type for `curl`.  And that's not the way to set it.

```
curl -X GET ...
```

That is the way to set `GET` as the *method keyword* that curl uses.

> It should be noted that curl selects which methods to use on its own depending on what action to ask for. -d will do POST, -I will do HEAD and so on. If you use the --request / -X option you can change the method keyword curl selects, but you will not modify curl's behavior. This means that if you for example use -d "data" to do a POST, you can modify the method to a PROPFIND with -X and curl will still think it sends a POST. You can change the normal GET to a POST method by simply adding -X POST in a command line like:

```
curl -X POST http://example.org/
```

> ... but curl will still think and act as if it sent a GET so it won't send any request body etc.

More here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#More_on_changed_methods

Again, that's not necessary.  Are you sure the link is correct?

Comment: ok, but in this way I must to have physical access to computers and in that case I can change the url!